# Space under content in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two DIV's. One is for holding the messages. The other for displaying the message content. But I have one problem. There is this big space under both of the DIV's. How do I fix it?

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid rgb(43, 68, 233);
  height: 770px;
  width: 300px;
}
#chat-content {
  height: 770px;
  width: 1283px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(43, 68, 233);
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 770px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='messages'>

  </div>
  <div id='chat-content'>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second div is positioned 770px from the bottom of the window : `bottom: 770px`.  This is what causes the gap.  Since you're dealing with defined, fixed widths, you can just use absolute positioning with `top` and `left`.  Keep in mind that `left` on your second div needs to accommodate for border width also (+2px) because your first box is actually 302px wide, not 300 (with the border).

```css
#messages {
   border: 1px solid rgb(43, 68, 233);
   height: 770px;
   width: 300px;
   position:absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
 }


 #chat-content {
   height: 770px;
   width: 1283px;
   border: 1px solid rgb(43, 68, 233);
   position:absolute;
   left: 302px;
   top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='messages'>
    </div>
    <div id='chat-content'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot!